# Non-toxic crayon bliyoth

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, meat-and-milk, bliyoth

Would a non-toxic, non-food substance, such as crayons, intentionally melted in a pan render it unkosher?  Does it matter if the crayons are known/suspected to contain both milk and meat (e.g. tallow/stearic acid and dairy-derived palmitic acid)?

Related:

- [Putting crayons in an oven](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75608/puttingcrayons-in-an-oven)
- [Do non-toxic, biodegradable kitchen/dish cleaners pose a Kashruth problem?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27884/do-non-toxic-biodegradable-kitchen-dish-cleaners-pose-a-kashruth-problem)

Comment: Most poskim hold that the prohibition of benefiting from milk and meat mixtures applies exclusively to kosher-slaughtered meat; the tallow used in some crayons would presumably be nevillah-tallow even in Israel

Comment: @Josh Na, maybe a minority of Poskim hold that