# Are crayons allowed?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, meat-and-milk, safek, issurei-hanaa

If a non-toxic (but also non-food) wax crayon is known/suspected to contain both meat (e.g. stearic acid; see e.g. [here](https://cool.conservation-us.org/waac/wn/wn19/wn19-3/wn19-308.html)) and milk (e.g. dairy-derived palmitic acid), may one use it or does it qualify as *issurei hanaah* (forbidden from benefit)?

Related:

- [Non-toxic crayon bliyoth](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98290/non-toxic-crayon-bliyoth)
- [Putting crayons in an oven](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75608/puttingcrayons-in-an-oven)
- [Do non-toxic, biodegradable kitchen/dish cleaners pose a Kashruth problem?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27884/do-non-toxic-biodegradable-kitchen-dish-cleaners-pose-a-kashruth-problem)

Comment: Stearic acid is not meat, palmitic acid is not milk. Additionally there are not at an edible stage, there are degraded from a eaten point of view.

Comment: non toxic is not synonym of food, edible, e.g. a stone may be non toxic, wood may be non toxic.but there are not food even for a dog

Comment: @kouty With sources, I'd accept your comments as answer(s).

Comment: I think we can all source that

Comment: I haven't looked at each link that you placed in your question. But, I think we can logically deduce that if a non-edible food wouldn't make the oven non-kosher, then there shouldn't be a problem handling it. I think all this follows the same rules.